Movie with a bow-like weapon whose wire/string that disintegrates people on contact
I remember seeing one scene from this live action movie somewhere around 2005-2011, I think. In the scene, I remember a dark and fiery setting. A woman had a weapon that I remember looking like a bow (), and the string looked like it was on fire too. The woman walked up to a dude on the ground, and he begged for mercy, but she hit him with the fiery string and he burst into flames and was reduced to his skeleton.
Some details may be off, and I can't imagine that the weapon was really a bow with the string as the dangerous part, but that's what I remember.

nice use of Bow emoji.

Blade 3, when we meets Whistlers niece, Abigail, the energy bow is her signature weapon, as per this clip:




Although, the guy on the ground gets taken out by a silver punch dagger.



This is exactly it (end of this clip https://youtu.be/KulM1fxkHV0). I doubted this answer at first because the scenery wasn't in fire, but the framing and blocking is exactly how I remember it. Even the presence of a second dude at the end was surprisingly familiar. Also, I cannot believe I was correct about the bow string. It felt so outlandish. Thank you so much, I've been wondering about this since I was probably 9 years old!

To be clear, the fancy disintegrations of these deaths weren't primarily due to the bow weapon itself. They were due to the fact that the victims were vampires. Exposure to sunlight had pretty much the same effect, and UV lights were also used as weapons in these films. It was perhaps implied that the bowstring was just a very bright light (a UV laser?) and therefore had the usual effect on the vampires.
